# Oracle, How To Apply one Payment to Several Invoices

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Table 1

| CUSTOMER | INVOICE | AMOUNT | PAID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1000,00 | 0,00 |
| 1 | 2 | 15205,20 | 0,00 |

Apply this Payment to previous Invoices Automatically
Table 2

| CUSTOMER | PAID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 16205,20 |

I Don't know how to start

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing down the logic of how you would do it manually and define your business logic.

For example:

1. You receive an amount of money.
2. You find the customer's invoices.
3. Select an unpaid invoice with the earliest id/earliest date/highest interest rate/lowest interest rate/highest amount owing/etc.
4. Increment the amount paid on that invoice by the lower of the amount received or the amount owed.
5. While there is still some received money not credited to an invoice then repeat from '3.

Once you have defined what your logic is then you can write a query or stored procedure that implements that logic; however **YOU** need to define your business logic first.

Comment: I'm system analyst, but i worked all my life with cobol. I know several oracle instructions but not all and honestly, i don't know how to do it

Comment: @RobertoBest Neither do we because you have not defined your business logic. When you know **WHAT** you need to do then we might be able to tell you **HOW** to do it. Until then we can't help because we cannot tell you how your business should behave.